# Not able to fetch data from graphQL in gatbsy

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

Here is my code:

```
class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      username: ``,
      password: ``,
    }
      ------------some lines of code
  }
export default Login

//////////////////////////////////// GraphQL ///////////////////////////////////

export const pageQuery = graphql`
query{
  users: allMysqlUsers{
    edges{
      node{
        name
        password
      }
    }
  }
}
`
```

Shouldn't I be able to fetch the data here by using:

```
const myData = this.props.data.users
```

If yes then where am I wrong?
If not then why, and what should be my approach for fetching and comparing the data from db.
Also, I'm following [this doc](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/authentication-tutorial/) for user-authentication using MySQL with gatsby. Any more suggestions/useful docs for me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: you will only be able to use a `pageQuery` in a top-level component (a page). If `<Login>` is a component (as it seems to be), you will need to use a `staticQuery`. You can check for further information: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/static-vs-normal-queries/.

### If it's a component:

```
import React from "react"
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"

export default function Login() {
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query{
      users: allMysqlUsers{
        edges{
          node{
            name
            password
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hi, {data.users.edges[0].node.name}</h1>
    </div>
  )
}
```

*Note: this scenario is based on a functional component rather than a stateful component. The approach is the same for both. However, I would recommend using a stateless (functional) component due to the use of React hooks. In this case, you will be able to use [`useStaticQuery` hook](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/blog/2019-02-20-introducing-use-static-query/#reach-skip-nav).*

### If it's a page (unlikely):

Your query is correct, however, your constant `myData` are missing some nested objects. Your `name` and `password` are inside:

```
const myData = this.props.data.users.edges[0].node
```

Of course, this will work for one user. If you have an array of users you should loop through `edges`:

```
{this.props.data.users.edges.map(node => <p key={node.name}>{node.name}, {node.password}</p>)}
```

Comment: Of course, I can loop through the edges, the problem is I can't get anything in the this.props.data. ```data``` is not there in the console if I log (this.props);

Comment: Is Login a page? If don't you will need to use a `staticQuery` instead of a `pageQuery`